# Using a generator matrix to find all code vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, coding-theory

I have a generator matrix below:
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}

$V$ is the binary linear code given by this matrix. Length $n = 5$, and dimension $K = 3$. I'm having trouble figuring out the process for finding all the code vectors from this matrix. I want to find them so I can find the min. distance of $V$. I should have $2^k$ codewords I think, so $2^3 = 8$ codewords total. What's the correct way for getting these codes?

Edit: So there are $2^k$ codewords, but I'm not sure how I multiply them together if the $\#$ of columns for the matrix is different than the number of rows for the vectors? IE matrix is $3\times6$ but the vectors are $3$ by $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a $k \times n$ generator matrix $G$ and message vector $m$ of length $k$, you can encode the message (i.e., find the code vector corresponding to that message vector) by computing $mG$.

To find all code vectors, simply repeat this computation for every possible value of $m$. As you observed, there are $2^k$ possible values of $m$ if you're working in binary.

Comment: What exactly is the message vector? Is it each column? Or every combination of those columns, so basically 000, 001, 010, 100, 011, 110, 101, 111. Not sure what the 9th one is. I would multiply them (in column form) by the generator matrix?

Comment: Wait, how can I multiply them if the number of columns is different than the number of rows for m?

Comment: The message vector is an arbitrary binary vector of length $k$. $m$ has dimensions $1 \times k$ and $G$ has dimensions $k \times n$, so $mG$ has dimensions $1 \times n$. If you prefer to use column vectors, then $m$ has dimensions $k \times 1$, so compute $(m^T G)^T = G^T m$ instead.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you!